# Oracle-Conveting SQL to ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, ansi-sql

This is regarding converting query to ANSI SQL. I tried writing this query with Oracle old syntax and it threw the following error so I ended  up changing it as shown below . After researching, I found that ANSI SQL supports such requirements.

ERROR :a table may be outer joined to at most one other table tips

Here is the query that I wrote which is working but it would be great to know if there are ways this can be re-written in ANSI-SQL or by using old outer join syntax. I am looking for the union queries to be re-written as others in the with clause work fine.

```
    WITH BOM_PARENT AS (
    SELECT MX.SAP_MATNR MATNR
         , TRIM(I.IPRODUCTION) IPRODUCTION
         , TRIM(I.IDRAWING) IDRAWING
         , TRIM(M.BCHLD) BCHLD
         , M.BSEQ BSEQ
         , PX.WERKS WERKS
         , M.BPSCP MENGE
         , UX.SAP_UOM MEINS
         , I.IUMS
     FROM XX_MAIN.XX_BPCS_IIM I
        , XX_MAIN.XX_BPCS_MPB M
        , XX_MAIN.XX_MATER_XREF MX
        , XX_MAIN.XX_TRUNK_XREF PX
        , XX_MAIN.XX_MP_UNIT_XREF UX
    WHERE TRIM(I.IPRODUCTION) = TRIM(M.BPROD) 
      AND TRIM(MX.PROD_MATNR) = TRIM(I.IPRODUCTION)
      AND MX.CONV_FACTOR = TO_CHAR(I.IUMCN) 
      AND I.IUMS  = UX.LEGACY_UOM
      AND UX.SOURCE = 'AP'
      AND I.SOURCE = PX.SOURCE
      AND I.ENTITY = PX.LEGACY_PLANT
      AND I.ENTITY = 'SG' 
      AND I.IITYP = '4'
      --AND PX.WERKS IN ('1379')
      AND MX.SAP_MTART <> 'ZPRD'
    )
    , BOM_CHILDS AS
    (
     SELECT  B.*,
             X.SAP_MATNR IDNRK
           , ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY B.MATNR,B.WERKS ORDER BY B.MATNR,B.WERKS) ID_ITEM_NO  
           , X.PROD_MATNR IDNRK_IPRODUCTION
           , X.DRAWING_MATNR IDNRK_IDRAWING     
      FROM  BOM_PARENT B
          , XX_MAIN.XX_MATER_XREF X
    WHERE  B.BCHLD = TRIM(X.PROD_MATNR )
      AND X.SAP_MTART <> 'ZPRD'
      AND X.SOURCE = 'AP'
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT C.MATNR
         , C.IPRODUCTION
         , C.IDRAWING
         , C.WERKS
         , (C.ID_ITEM_NO*10) ID_ITEM_NO
         , C.BSEQ
         , C.IDNRK
         , C.IDNRK_IPRODUCTION
         , C.IDNRK_IDRAWING
         , C.MENGE BPSCP
         , STPO.MENGE  STPO_MENGE
         , C.MEINS MEINS
         , C.IUMS IUMS
         , STPO.MEINS STPO_MEINS
      FROM BOM_CHILDS C
         , XX_MAIN.XX_MAST MAST
         , XX_MAIN.XX_STPO STPO
      WHERE C.MATNR = MAST.MATNR
       AND MAST.STLNR = STPO.STLNR
       AND MAST.STLAN = '1'
       AND MAST.WERKS = C.WERKS
       AND STPO.IDNRK = C.IDNRK
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT C.MATNR
         , C.IPRODUCTION
         , C.IDRAWING
         , C.WERKS
         , (C.ID_ITEM_NO*10) ID_ITEM_NO
         , C.BSEQ
         , C.IDNRK
         , C.IDNRK_IPRODUCTION
         , C.IDNRK_IDRAWING
         , C.MENGE BPSCP
         , STPO.MENGE  STPO_MENGE
         , C.MEINS MEINS
         , C.IUMS IUMS
         , STPO.MEINS STPO_MEINS
      FROM BOM_CHILDS C
         , XX_MAIN.XX_MAST MAST
         , XX_MAIN.XX_STPO STPO
      WHERE C.MATNR = MAST.MATNR(+)
       AND MAST.STLNR = STPO.STLNR(+)
       AND MAST.STLAN(+) = '1'
       AND MAST.WERKS(+) = C.WERKS
       AND STPO.IDNRK IS NULL
    ORDER BY MATNR,WERKS,ID_ITEM_NO,BSEQ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section is probably causing the problem:

```
  FROM BOM_CHILDS C
     , XX_MAIN.XX_MAST MAST
     , XX_MAIN.XX_STPO STPO
  WHERE C.MATNR = MAST.MATNR(+)
   AND MAST.STLNR = STPO.STLNR(+)
   AND MAST.STLAN(+) = '1'
   AND MAST.WERKS(+) = C.WERKS
   AND STPO.IDNRK IS NULL
```

To make this a bit easier, lets rearrange the `WHERE` clause to order the tables by how they relate:

```
FROM BOM_CHILDS C
 , XX_MAIN.XX_MAST MAST
 , XX_MAIN.XX_STPO STPO
-- Joining C to MAST
WHERE C.MATNR = MAST.MATNR(+)
  AND C.WERKS = MAST.WERKS(+)
  AND MAST.STLAN(+) = '1'
-- Joining MAST to STPO
  AND MAST.STLNR = STPO.STLNR(+)
  AND STPO.IDNRK IS NULL
```

---

We have `C` joined to `MAST` using `C` as the "driver" table and picking up data from `MAST` where it matches (a left join):

```
FROM BOM_CHILDS C
LEFT JOIN XX_MAIN.XX_MAST MAST
  ON C.MANTR = MAST.MANTR
 AND C.WERKS = MAST.WERKS
 AND MAST.STLAN = '1'
```

Then we need to add `STPO` to the joins:

```
LEFT JOIN XX_MAIN.XX_STPO STPO
  ON MAST.STLNR = STPO.STLNR
 AND STPO.IDNRK IS NULL
```

---

Putting it all together we get:

```
FROM BOM_CHILDS C
LEFT JOIN XX_MAIN.XX_MAST MAST
  ON C.MANTR = MAST.MANTR
 AND C.WERKS = MAST.WERKS
 AND MAST.STLAN = '1'
LEFT JOIN XX_MAIN.XX_STPO STPO
  ON MAST.STLNR = STPO.STLNR
 AND STPO.IDNRK IS NULL
```

---

**That said**, even though `(+)` works for left/right/outer joins, [Oracle recommends **not** using it](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354):

> Oracle recommends that you use the `FROM` clause `OUTER JOIN` syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator `(+)` are subject to the following rules and restrictions, which do not apply to the `FROM` clause `OUTER JOIN` syntax: ...

Comment: Thanks @ Mr Llama..How do I get not null values of stpo.idnrk as in STPO.IDNRK = C.IDNRK along with null values (The first query in my union query retrieves matching IDNRKs). Is it possible to have this logic in just one query instead of writing union.

Comment: That's what the outer join does.  Where it matches, you get a value, when it doesn't, you get NULL.  Unioning the results of an inner join with an outer join will always give the same result as just the outer join alone.

Comment: @Tina - If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure @ Mr Llama. However, this is the join i had which didnt work and i ended up writing two union queries...... Please take a look and let me know your inputs.  This threw the error I mentioned in my question above       :                                                                                              WHERE C.MATNR = MAST.MATNR(+)
       AND MAST.STLNR = STPO.STLNR(+)
       AND MAST.STLAN(+) = '1'
       AND MAST.WERKS(+) = C.WERKS
       AND STPO.IDNRK(+) = C.IDNRK.